# How to call a system command without printing anything?

Tags: python

On running following python snippet -

```
from subprocess import call
call(['zip', '-d', 'ya', 'yo'])
```

It prints this output -

```
    zip warning: ya.zip not found or empty
    zip warning: name not matched: yo

zip error: Nothing to do! (ya.zip)
12
```

How do I suppress the output or redirect it to a buffer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the `stdout` and `stdin` keyword arguments](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) to `call` to redirect the streams to (among other things) file objects. So you could write:

```
import os
from subprocess import call

with open(os.devnull) as devnull:
    call(['zip', '-d', 'ya', 'yo'], stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)
```

In python 3.3 or higher, you can do this directly with [`subprocess.DEVNULL`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DEVNULL):

```
call(['zip', '-d', 'ya', 'yo'], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the output to `/dev/null`, e. g. by using the shell feature of `call`:

```
call('zip -d ya yo > /dev/null 2>&1', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **subprocess.check_output** function - nearly same interface, returns command output